# IE8 display images, Chrome / Firefox doesn't display images with BlockUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, blockui

IE8 display images, Chrome / Firefox doesn't display images with BlockUI

My code is:

```
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            $.blockUI({ 
                theme: true,
                title: '<img src="images/titulo.png" />',
                message: '<center><p><img src="images/spinner.gif" /></p><p><img src="images/mensagem.png" /></p></center>'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with this same issue today, and finally found a solution. BlockUI seems to have trouble loading images when an action fires to load another page. However, if you preload your images in your JS before your click event, it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  //preload your images here
  img1 = new Image();
  img1.src = "images/titulo.png";
  img2 = new Image();
  img2.src = "images/spinner.gif";

  $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
    $.blockUI({
      theme: true,
      title: '<img src="images/titulo.png" />',
      message: '<center><p><img src="images/spinner.gif" /></p><p><img src="images/mensagem.png" /></p></center>'
    });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
thanks is work fine
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){        
        var url='<?= base_url(); ?>'; 
        img2 = new Image();
        img2.src = "<?=$this->config->item('base_url')?>images/6.gif";


             jQuery.blockUI({ message: '<h3 style="height:80px;background:#212121;font-weight:bold;color:#fff;padding:0px; margin:0px;  border: none;" ><br/>Please Wait While Loading... <img src="<?=$this->config->item('base_url')?>images/6.gif" title="Loading..." alt=""  style="padding:0px; margin:0px;" /><br/></h3>'});
        }); 

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is this your answer or question?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution, for me, was to preload the image in the JSP so it can be properly displayed when called in the JS file:

```
     <div style="display: none;"> 
        <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="" /> 
     </div>
```